# How to append to a json file on the fly?

Tags: python, json, file, dictionary

I am parsing several thousands html files which come out as a dict. Then I want to combine them as one dict and save to disk in json format.

I don't want to build this huge dict in memory while iterating through files, I would rather keep updating/writing to a file as I go.

So instead of this:

```
data = {}
for e, fn in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):
    fp = os.path.join(path, fn)
    d = html_to_dict(fp)
    data[e] = d
```

I would like this:

```
with open('out_file.json', 'w') as f:
    for e, fn in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):
        fp = os.path.join(path, fn)
        d = html_to_dict(fp)
        # update the file dict
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to do this by writing some of the JSON yourself and just using the `json` library for the individual records. For example:

```
with open('out_file.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write("{")
    delim = ""
    for e, fn in enumerate(os.listdir(path)):
        fp = os.path.join(path, fn)
        d = html_to_dict(fp)
        f.write(delim + str(e) + ":")
        json.dump(d, f)
        delim = ",\n"
    f.write("}")
```

In this case you could write an array instead of an object and save the space required for the keys:

```
with open('out_file.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write("[")
    delim = ""
    for fn in os.listdir(path):
        fp = os.path.join(path, fn)
        d = html_to_dict(fp)
        f.write(delim)
        json.dump(d, f)
        delim = ",\n"
    f.write("]")
```